# Check more than one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get text those item which having a particular class or no class or have not two class.

Here is my html code -

```
<div id="events">
    <ul class="checkout-bar">
        <li class=""><span><a href="#">Order</a></span></li>
        <li class=""><span><a href="#">Booking</a></span></li>
        <li class="t-completed"><span><a href="#">Receiving</a></span></li>
        <li class="t-completed"><span><a href="#">Loading</a></span></li>
        <li class="t-completed active"><span><a href="#">Arrival</a></span></li>
        <li class="inactive"><span><a href="#">Arrival</a></span></li>
        <li class="inactive"><span><a href="#">Availability</a></span></li>
        <li class="inactive"><span><a href="#">Delivery</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I want to get Text of those link tag () which `li` having '`t-completed`' class and which having empty class and which have not '`t-completed`' and  '`active`' class i.e `<li class="t-completed active">`

Try with Jquery -

```
if($('#events .checkout-bar li').length>0){
    $('#events .checkout-bar li').each(function(){  
        var t = $(this);
        if (!t.hasClass() || (t.hasClass("ms-completed") && !t.hasClass("active"))){

        //if($(this).is('.ms-completed:not(.active)') || $(this).attr('class')==""){
            var oldtxt = $(t).find('span a').text();
            if(oldtxt == 'Order'){
                t.find('span a').text("Ordered");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Booking'){
                t.find('span a').text("Booked");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Receiving'){
                t.find('span a').text("Received");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Loading'){
                t.find('span a').text("Loaded");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Arrival'){
                t.find('span a').text("Arrived");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Availability'){
                t.find('span a').text("Available");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'Delivery'){
                t.find('span a').text("Delivered");
            }else if(oldtxt == 'In transit'){
                t.find('span a').text("Transited");
            }else{
                t.find('span a').text(oldtxt);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Replace those `<a>` tag text which `<li>` having empty `("")` class and which having `"ms-completed"` class only. Currently, replace those `<a>` tag text which `<li>` having "ms-completed active' class.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `hasClass()` here:

```
var t = $(this);
if (t.attr("class") === '' || (t.hasClass("t-completed") && !t.hasClass("active"))) {....}
```

UPDATE: I don't know if you have this line in your actual code:

```
var oldtxt = $(t).find('span a').text();
```

but t already equals `$(this)` so don't wrap t again in `$()`.

Also, this should be sufficient for `oldtxt` (based on your shown HTML above):

```
var oldtxt = t.text();
```